# Word for list of mutual followers or following

Tags: single-word-requests

In Twitter there is a follower list and a following list of a person. Just like that, suppose two user are following each other, then what would be the appropriate (if possible a cool word) term for this kind of list where only mutual followers/following are listed?

I thought of going with *Mutual*, but its really not cool at all. Could you please help me figure it out?

Comment: The are 'reciprocal' followers maybe?

Comment: There is the FFR (Follower-Friend Ratio) but it's more of a ranking system than a list.

Comment: It reminds me of a [symmetric relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_relation) in mathematics. Obviously the follower relation is not symmetrical at all.

Comment: @JohnFeltz Yes I will try to find a synonym for 'reciprocal`

Comment: @Glorfindel Yes I also thought the same!

Comment: Many apps/sites simply call them **friends**.

Comment: hmmm .... a cool word?

Comment: Why is that difficult, please? If "two user are following each other…" they are mutual followers. that's what "mutual" means.

Clearly, the modern tendency t warp "mutual" into "shared" might mess you up, but what did your dictionaries say?

Comment: Friends and friends of friends are *connections* that form a *social network*.

Answer (score 1):

**Since it's not a popularly used thing, there may not be a right word for it yet.**

But there are some examples available on Google (and Google Books) for ["**reciprocal followers**"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22reciprocal%20followers%22), and I'd second what John Feltz suggested.

*Reciprocal* -- [Vocabulary](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/reciprocal)

> *Reciprocal* describes something that's the same on both sides. If you and your sister are in a big fight on a long car trip, you might resolve it through a reciprocal agreement that you'll stop poking her and she'll stop reading road signs out loud.
>
> The word *mutual* is a near synonym in most uses: *reciprocal*/*mutual* friendship, describing, a relationship in which two people feel the same way about each other, or do or give similar things to each other. If you tell someone you like them and they say, "The feelings are reciprocal," that means they like you too. In math, a reciprocal is a number that when multiplied by a given number gives one as a product.

I'd also suggest ["**reciprocated follower**"](https://www.google.com/search?&q=%22reciprocated%20follower%22), which, again, has some usage examples on Google.

*Reciprocate* -- [Vocabulary](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/reciprocate)

> You reciprocate when you return a favor, return a compliment, or respond "the same to you" to the angry guy in the car you just passed. In short, you react to an action, statement, or emotion by mirroring it.
>
> This one comes from the Latin verb reciprocare, meaning to move back and forth. Its root makes it sound as if reciprocate implies only a physical action, but it's also used for the less tangible. If you fail to pay the rent, your landlord might reciprocate by evicting you. If your crush acts like he doesn't know you exist when you pass him in the halls, it's probably safe to say he does not reciprocate your amorous feelings.

Answer (score 0):

If you think *friend* is too strong of a relationship to describe people that are following each other, you can try ***peer***:

> A person of the same age, status, or ability as another specified person.
>   '*he has incurred much criticism from his academic **peers***'
>   <sub>[Oxford *Living* Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/peer)</sub>

In this case, the sameness is that you follow each other. It ties-in with the verb form:

> Look with difficulty or concentration at someone or something.
>   '*Faye **peered** at her with suspicion*'
>   <sub>[Oxford *Living* Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/peer)</sub>

That is, in a sense, you are looking at each other.